# Overloading an enum in a child class in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm interested in defining a general class to be inherited that operates differently based on an enum and map of that enum to some data structure.

In the following code I have test_child inherit from test_parent, which has the shared functions already implemented. My plan would be to have many classes inherit from a class like parent_class, but to define a unique 'field' enum and corresponding 'mapping' map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class test_parent {
public:
    enum class field {
        A,
        B,
        C
    };

    typedef struct {
        std::string s;
        int i, j;
    } data_t;

    std::unordered_map<field, data_t> mapping {
        {field::A, {"A", 1, 1}},
        {field::B, {"B", 2, 2}},
        {field::C, {"C", 3, 3}}
    };

    int get_i (field f) {
        return mapping[f].i;
    }

    std::string get_s (field f) {
        return mapping[f].s;
    }   
};

class test_child : test_parent {
public:
    enum class field {
        D,
        E
    };

    std::unordered_map<field, data_t> mapping {
        {field::D, {"D", 4, 4}},
        {field::E, {"E", 5, 5}}
    };
};

int main () {
    test_parent tp;
    test_child tc;

    std::cout << tp.get_i(test_parent::field::A) << " " << tc.get_i(test_child::field::E) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code returns a compilation error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:55:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘test_child::get_i(test_child::field)’
std::cout << tp.get_i(test_parent::field::A) << " " << tc.get_i(test_child::field::E) << std::endl;
                                                                                    ^
test.cpp:28:6: note: candidate: int test_parent::get_i(test_parent::field)
int get_i (field f) {
    ^~~~~
test.cpp:28:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘test_child::field’ to ‘test_parent::field’
```

But What I expect to be printed is:

```
1 5
```

Comment: Sadly, there is no easy answer here. There are only complex or weakly typed answers.

Comment: Did you want all of those data objects and such to be static? Right now it seems wierd that each `test_parent` instance has it's own map of enums to data.

Comment: There's no such thing like _overloading an enum value_, sorry.

Comment: As I think more, you probably _can_ do this, based on making a custom `enum`-like type...

Comment: A use case for this will help to get you a better answer.  Right now `test_child::field` and `test_parent::field` are completely separate types.

Comment: I made a mess! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/debebc120ac56f0e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it is what you want, but with template, you might do

```
struct data_t
{
    std::string s;
    int i;
    int j;
};

template <typename E>
class test_parent {
public:
    int get_i(E e) const { return mapping.at(e).i; }
    const std::string& get_s(E e) const { return mapping.at(e).s; }

    static const std::unordered_map<E, data_t> mapping;
};
```

And then

```
enum class field_ABC{ A, B, C };
enum class field_DE{ D, E };

template <>
const std::unordered_map<field_ABC , data_t> test_parent<field_ABC >::mapping =  {
    {field_ABC::A, {"A", 1, 1}},
    {field_ABC::B, {"B", 2, 2}},
    {field_ABC::C, {"C", 3, 3}}
};

template <>
const std::unordered_map<field_DE, data_t> test_parent<field_DE>::mapping =  {
    {field_DE::D, {"D", 4, 4}},
    {field_DE::E, {"E", 5, 5}}
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5e7a4232c8001f7)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that I may have found an answer in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class test_parent {
public:
    enum class field {
        A,
        B,
        C
    };

    typedef struct {
        std::string s;
        int i, j;
    } data_t;

    std::unordered_map<uint, data_t> mapping {
        {(uint) field::A, {"A", 1, 1}},
        {(uint) field::B, {"B", 2, 2}},
        {(uint) field::C, {"C", 3, 3}}
    };

    int get_i (uint f) {
        return mapping[f].i;
    }

    std::string get_s (uint f) {
        return mapping[f].s;
    }   
};

class test_child : public test_parent {
public:
    test_child () {
        test_parent::mapping = mapping;
    }

    enum class field {
        D = 4,
        E = 5
    };

    std::unordered_map<uint, data_t> mapping {
        {(uint) field::E, {"E", 5, 5}},
        {(uint) field::D, {"D", 4, 4}}
    };
};

int main () {
    test_parent tp;
    test_child tc;

    std::cout << tp.get_i((uint) test_parent::field::A) << " " << tc.get_i((uint) test_child::field::E) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Where I treat the enum values like they are originally conceived to be, ints!

Comment: *"I treat the `enum` values like they are originally conceived to be, `int`s"*. Maybe for your purpose, but not the (strong) type system...

Comment: It seems you don't want `enum class`, but simply `enum` (so you can get rid of cast to `int`).

Comment: This breaks horribly as soon as I add a `G` member to `parent::field`.